# How to save Traceback error information into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, error-handling, traceback

Say I have a very simple code that raises an error:

```
print(1/0)
```

How do I save the full traceback error into a file, so that the file contains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html) standard library module is useful for manipulating traceback errors in python, just get a file object and then use it to write the traceback into the file:

```py
import traceback

with open('tb.txt', 'w+') as f:
    try:
        print(1/0)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)
```

I opened a file in write mode (and create it if file doesn’t exist), save the object as `f`, and then wrap the part that throws an error in `try-except` block. This is needed because the moment the error happens the program is terminated with the error printed, so we won’t have time to save the trace back.

After that, in the `except` part, we use the `print_exc()` To save the traceback into the file.

> `traceback.print_exc(limit=None, file=None, chain=True)`
>
> This is a shorthand for `print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), limit, file, chain)`.

Remember don’t just pass the file name as a string, the `file` argument needs to have a `write()` method that writes to the file. Putting the opening/closing of file ensures that the file is closed after doing work with it.

Results of **tb.txt**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: My mistake was pointing the file argument to the filename rather than its corresponding filehandle - thank you.

Comment: How to save date and time of error in above text file